# What predicate do I use to fetch distinct objects in a many to one to one relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

The entity relations are as follows

```
Effect <->> EffectFilterProperty <<-> FilterProperty <<-> Filter
```

I need all distinct filters related to a particular effect (which can be filtered by its "name" property). What sort of predicate do I need to use for this relationship?

Relationship names are as follows:

```
Effect ->> EffectFilterProperty is filterPropertyValues
EffectFilterProperty -> FilterProperty is relatedFilterProperty
FilterProperty -> Filter is belongsToFilter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the *inverse relationships* to fetch the filters related to a effect.
The precise answer depends on which inverse relationships are to-one and which are
to-many. For example, if you have

- "filterProperty" as to-one relationship from "Filter" to "FilterProperty",
- "effectFilters" as to-many relationship from "FilterProperty" to "EffectFilterProperty",
- "effect" as to-one relationship from "EffectFilterProperty" to "Effect",

then you would execute a fetch request on the "Filter" entity with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY filterProperty.effectFilters.effect.name = %@",
       theEffectName];
```

If all inverse relationships are to-one then omit the "ANY". If more than one
inverse relationship is to-many then it is slightly more complicated and you need
a predicate using "SUBQUERY".

*Update* according to the updated question: "ANY" does not work with more than one
nested to-many relationship, you need a "SUBQUERY":

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(filterProperties, $fp, ANY $fp.effectFilterProperties.effect.name = %@).@count > 0", effectName];
```

About fetching "distinct" objects: A fetch request always returns distinct managed
objects, it will never return the same object twice. - If you need objects having
distinct *values* for some or all attributes, then you have to set the fetch request
`resultType` to `NSDictionaryResultType` and `returnsDistinctResults` to `YES`.

Comment: BTW there is no "DISTINCT" SQL keyword type functionality with core data right?

Comment: Actually there are more than one to many inverse relationships as you mentioned... I have updated the question with the relationships on both sides.

Comment: wont  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY filterProperties.effectFilterProperties.effect.name = %@", effectName]; work in that case?

Comment: @AviralBajpai: I have updated the answer with something that should work (of course there may be typos).